# Hadoop Hive Error

Tags: csv

I have below data i used struct and iam not getting proper output.

```
create table data(id int,name string, dept string,address STRUCT<doornumber:String, street:String, state:String>)
    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    > FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    > COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
    > STORED AS TEXTFILE;
OK
Time taken: 0.129 seconds
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/Desktop/sample' OVERWRITE into table data;
Loading data to table default.data
Table default.data stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=237, rawDataSize=0]
OK
Time taken: 0.547 seconds
hive> select * from data;
OK
1   javeed  IT  {"doornumber":"10","street":null,"state":null}
2   nag IT  {"doornumber":"11","street":null,"state":null}
3   gupta   ITIS    {"doornumber":"15","street":null,"state":null}
4   Ajay    Finance {"doornumber":"12","street":null,"state":null}
5   Naddu   Electric    {"doornumber":"11","street":null,"state":null}
6   Radhava Pharma  {"doornumber":"15","street":null,"state":null}
7   Arshad  Finance {"doornumber":"13","street":null,"state":null}                          
8   Srinu   Telecom {"doornumber":"14","street":null,"state":null}
```

Comment: Title says error, but none is given in the question. Question says "not getting proper output", but how can we guess what that could be?

Answer (score 0):

Note that , field and collection delimiter used is same i.e. `","` ( `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` and `COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','`). Same delimiter can not be used for field as well as collection. Whenever `,` occurs next text will be treated as new field. Hence `select` query output is not as expected (i.e. `null` is seen).

Modify data to delimit collection items with some other characters (e.g. ":") and similarly corresponding text file.

Example:

**Text File with , delimited fields and : delimited collection items.**

```
cat a.txt 
1,name1,IT,11:str1:stat1
2,name2,IT,12:str1:stat1
```

**Create table Statement**

```
create table data1(id int,name string, dept string,address STRUCT<doornumber:String, street:String, state:String>)
     ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ':'
     STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```